# Upload file using retrofit 2 even if null

Tags: java, android, file, upload, retrofit2

I have an application where the user can add comment, location and optional image to the SqlLiteDatabse. On a button press a sync images will sync all images in the db (by path of course). My problem is when the file is null, it will return onFaiulre com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException.

```
private void syncImage(final int id, String imagePath, String message, String location) {
    final SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    File file = null;
    if(imagePath!= null && !imagePath.equals(""))
    file = new File(imagePath);

    alertDialog.setTitle("Uploading.. ");
    alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            dialogInterface.dismiss();
        }
    });

    MultipartBody.Part uploaded_file = null;
    if(file !=null) {
        RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);

        uploaded_file =
                MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("uploaded_file", file.getName(), requestFile);
    }
    RequestBody image_message =
            RequestBody.create(
                    MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), message);

    RequestBody user_location =
            RequestBody.create(
                    MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), location);

    Call<String> call = new ApiService().getApiService().upload(image_message, user_location, uploaded_file);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<String> call, retrofit2.Response<String> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                progressDialog.setProgress(progressDialog.getProgress() + singleProgress);
                ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
                contentValues.put(ImageContract.IMAGE_SYNKED, "true");
                db.update(ImageContract.TABLE_NAME, contentValues, ImageContract.IMAGE_ID + "=" + id, null);
                Log.d("retrofit", "image uploaded");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("db", t.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

I'm wondering how can I upload an optional file ?

Log:

```
db: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    String mem_email_str = edit_email.getText().toString().trim();
    RequestBody mem_email = RequestBody.create(MultipartBody.FORM,mem_email_str);
    MultipartBody.Part body = null;
    Call<String> call;

    if(profile_file != null){
        RequestBody file = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"),profile_file);
        body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file",profile_file.getName(),file);
        call = httpService.mobileInsertMember(mem_email,body);
    }else{
        RequestBody file = RequestBody.create(MultipartBody.FORM,"");
        body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file","",file);
        call = httpService.mobileInsertMember(mem_email,body);
    }
```